# WordPress multisite , shows all sites but only want to display last 2

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display the last 2 posts of a network of sites. Currently I'm retrieving all latest posts for all sites but only want to display 2 of them.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
  $items = return_latest_posts();
  global $wpdb;
  $table_search = $wpdb->prefix . "searchinfo";
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `$table_search`";
  $wpdb->show_errors();
  $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

  foreach ($results as $site){
    $item = return_latest_posts_single_site($site->username,$site->password,$site->database,$site->host,$site->db_prefix);
  ?>

<li>
  <h4><?php echo $site->sitename; ?></h4>

  <?php foreach($item as $res){  ?>
    <p class="date"><?php echo $res->post_date ?></p>
    <h4><a href="<?php echo $res->guid; ?>" target='_blank'><?php echo $res->post_title ?></a></h4>
  <?php } ?>

  <hr />

</li>

<?php } ?>
```

How am I able to only show the last 2 posts of all sites together?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider counting the number of times that the $results foreach runs and restricting output to the first two laps:

```
<?php
  $items = return_latest_posts();
  global $wpdb;
  $table_search = $wpdb->prefix . "searchinfo";
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `$table_search`";
  $wpdb->show_errors();
  $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

  $count = 0;
  foreach ($results as $site){

    $count++;
    $item = return_latest_posts_single_site($site->username,$site->password,$site->database,$site->host,$site->db_prefix);

    if ( $count < 3) {

  ?>

    <li>
      <h4><?php echo $site->sitename; ?></h4>

      <?php foreach($item as $res){  ?>
        <p class="date"><?php echo $res->post_date ?></p>
        <h4><a href="<?php echo $res->guid; ?>" target='_blank'><?php echo $res->post_title ?></a></h4>
      <?php } ?>

      <hr />

    </li>

<?php }} ?>
```

[More information on $wpdb;](http://wpdb.webstuffdepot.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer James. Problem is that I still get for every network (7 sites) + 1 post. I only want to show the latest network updates (2 latest posts).

Comment: I think I was misreading your goal. Is this accurate: The goal is to display only two blog posts, and those posts should be the most recent posts on the network?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for!

Comment: See my edit - the $count can be moved into the higher level foreach to return the first two counts of the site level data. I don't know if the data in $results are already ordered by post date correctly? Are the first two results actually also the most recent posts, or are they just the first two results that were found?

Comment: Thanks, but somehow it doesn't display anything =(. The $results is ordered corractly as it shows the last post of each network.

Comment: Odd that it returned nothing. It appeared correct to me. Unfortunately, I am not able to run the code! I had made several elective edits to the last example. I've reposted with fewer edits. Perhaps one of my elective edits threw off your script.

Comment: Retried your code, played around with the if ( $count > 3) { and now I have 2 posts, BIG THANKS! . Problem a nice temporary fix.

Comment: Right! We needed a 'less than' symbol in there. Good eye. I've corrected my answer, if you'd like to mark it as your selected answer.